# URI to assets' subfolder does not work

Tags: android, media-player, uri

I want to get the duration of a sound file and found a solution here on Stack Overflow that requires the URI to the specific sound. I tried the following:

```
String path = "file:///android_asset/" + soundFolder + "/" + soundArray[currentSound];
// cutting off ".wav" extension:
path = path.substring(0, path.length() - 4);
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(path));
int duration = mp.getDuration();
mp.release();
```

`soundFolder` is a `String` containing the name of the subfolder inside the assets folder, where all sound files are located.

`soundArray` is a `String` array that contains the name (e. g. "sound04.wav") of each sound inside the `soundFolder`.

Apparently the `MediaPlayer` fails to initialize because the URI is faulty. I could not find any other way to get to the assets folder and have no understanding of URIs. Where does the mistake lie?

Comment: you can place your files in res/raw folder and use R.raw.someFile

Comment: @pskink Is there no way to do it inside the assets folder? If I remember correctly, it is nicer to have items like sound files there, instead of inside the res folder?!

Comment: yes you can do that,  you need special Uri for that: your custom content provider

Comment: @pskink Can you please give me an example? I looked quite some time but could not figure it out...

Comment: go to google.com and type: contentprovider assets folder

Comment: @pskink I already tried that, as you can see above. "file:///android_asset/" + soundFolder + "/" + soundArray[currentSound] is basically "file:///android_asset/sounds/sound04.wav". So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what have you tried?  try first links from that http://www.google.com/m?q=contentprovider+assets+folder+&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57058/discussion-between-j0hj0h-and-pskink).

Comment: just realized that you dont have to use MediaPlayer.create(), you may try to use setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd) and see if it works with AssetManager returned data

Comment: @pskink `mp.setDataSource(getAssets().openFd(SOUND_FOLDER + "/" + soundArray[currentSound - 1]).getFileDescriptor());` throws an IOException: `java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000` I already converted the sound files from .wav to .ogg, but the error remains. Thanks, anyway! That seemed like a good idea! I do not know where I messed up...

Comment: try AssetManager.list to get the paths of your assets

Comment: That is how I filled the `soundArray`. It is the `String` array that is returned by `AssetManager.list()`.

Comment: try open() and see if you can read the stream, that way you will make sure you pass the valid path

Comment: I think you mean using an `InputStream`. I have no experience with them and find them quite complicated. Also, I do not need to implement this now, so I will probably just give up on it for now. I still have many things to learn about Android, as you already know. ;)

Comment: ok,  i looked into MadiaPlayer source code and saw what MediaPlayer.create is doing,  now its clear how to use it with assets,  do the same and you will know what to do in your code

Answer (score 0):

The notation "file:///android_asset/...." is only understood by a WebView. Apps will have to use the assets manager to open an inputstream for a file in assets and read from it. If the MediaPlayer cannot be initialised with that stream then you should use a content provider or copy the file to external memory.